# Can't create a large VeraCrypt partition in hard drive "found a atari partition in /dev/mapper/veracrypt1"

Tags: partitioning, veracrypt

I have got a little problem with formatting a hard drive as a VeraCrypt container. This is the first time in my life a program has told me

> mk2fs (...) Found a atari partition in /dev/mapper/veracrypt1.

I do not have any idea what it means or how I can fix it.

I think the hard drive is OK (it's brand new) because I can create a partition with no filesystem and then I am able to create a VeraCrypt container in this partition, but these partitions have to be very small.

It is possible to create a VeraCrypt container on this drive in 5 GB partition, 50 GB partition, but in a 1.5 TB partition it crashes as described above.

I create a standard VC container (not hidden).

[image: screenshot with context for the mkfs message - VeraCrypt GUI Volume Format settings with popup alert]

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not that weird... Before encrypting your drive, you probably created a new partition table.
When I create a new partition table on a drive with GParted, I get the following possible values :
[image: Possible partition tables with GParted]

So usually I choose msdos or gpt, but atari is obviously a possibility. Maybe you created the partition table without noticing this setting ?

So I would suggest to back up the drive content (if there is any...), reformat it by creating a new partition table, and encrypt it again with Veracrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I also used GParted -> Device -> Create Partition Table -> msdos and now it is working without problems.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190761)